# How to fix backgroundColor assignment error?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When assigning `backgroundColor` to a random `div`, an error appears: `"TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined" (82 line)`

```
79 | const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
80 | 
81 | 
82 | duel[randomNumber].style.backgroundColor='blue';



render(){
    const duel = ['duel1', 'duel2', 'duel3', 'duel4', 'duel5', 'duel6',
            'duel7', 'duel8', 'duel9', 'duel10', 'duel11', 'duel12', 'duel13',
            'duel14', 'duel15', 'duel16', 'duel17', 'duel18', 'duel19', 'duel20',
            'duel21', 'duel22', 'duel23', 'duel24', 'duel25'];

    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
    duel[randomNumber].style.backgroundColor='blue';

    return (
            <div>
                 <div>
                    <button>Play</button>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    here it is 25 div      
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: duel[randomNumber] is not an element. its only a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is more what you are going for, you need to add some kind of identifier to the div then getElementsByClassName (in the case of class name) to get the actual element instead of just a string.

```
render(){
const duel = ['duel1', 'duel2', 'duel3', 'duel4', 'duel5', 'duel6',
            'duel7', 'duel8', 'duel9', 'duel10', 'duel11', 'duel12', 'duel13',
            'duel14', 'duel15', 'duel16', 'duel17', 'duel18', 'duel19', 'duel20',
            'duel21', 'duel22', 'duel23', 'duel24', 'duel25'];

const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
const elementClassName = duel[randomNumber]
document.getElementsByClassName(elementClassName).style.backgroundColor='blue';

 return (
            <div>
                 <div>
                    <button>Play</button>
                </div>
                 <div className='duel25'>
                    here it is 25 div      
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: also , since the duel array index goes from 0 to 24, getting the randomNumber like that would not be a good idea. try just elementClassName='duel' + randomNumber

Answer (score 0):

The `duel` is neither a DOM element, neither a React element with the `style` property; it's a string.

If you want to randomly change the background color of some element, you should try to:

1. Create a React element (or DOM element, e.g. `<div />`).
2. Put the element to an array(e.g. `duel`).
3. Change styles via `duel[randomNumber].style.backgroundColor='blue';`